# How to get callback/update when using tokio::io::copy?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

`tokio::io::copy` doesn't provide progress update callbacks. When `copy` takes much time to complete, it is good to report progress of the copy operation. Is there a way to get status/progress when copy happens?

Answer (score 0):

The [`tokio::io::copy`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.copy.html) function simply works off the `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite` traits. I'm not sure if there's anything pre-built, but its not too bad to write your own adapter to display progress:

```
use std::io::Result;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::time::Duration;

use pin_project::pin_project;
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, ReadBuf};
use tokio::time::{interval, Interval};

#[pin_project]
pub struct ProgressReadAdapter<R: AsyncRead> {
    #[pin]
    inner: R,
    interval: Interval,
    interval_bytes: usize,
}

impl<R: AsyncRead> ProgressReadAdapter<R> {
    pub fn new(inner: R) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner,
            interval: interval(Duration::from_millis(100)),
            interval_bytes: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<R: AsyncRead> AsyncRead for ProgressReadAdapter<R> {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
        let this = self.project();

        let before = buf.filled().len();
        let result = this.inner.poll_read(cx, buf);
        let after = buf.filled().len();

        *this.interval_bytes += after - before;
        match this.interval.poll_tick(cx) {
            Poll::Pending => {}
            Poll::Ready(_) => {
                println!("reading at {} bytes per second", *this.interval_bytes * 10);
                *this.interval_bytes = 0;
            }
        };

        result
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
use tokio::fs::File;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut file1 = File::open("foo.bin").await?;
    let mut file2 = File::create("bar.bin").await?;

    let mut file1 = ProgressReadAdapter::new(file1);

    tokio::io::copy(&mut file1, &mut file2).await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

```
reading at 38338560 bytes per second
reading at 315146240 bytes per second
reading at 422625280 bytes per second
reading at 497827840 bytes per second
reading at 428605440 bytes per second
```

You could probably make this look nicer by hooking it up to [indicatif](https://crates.io/crates/indicatif) or at least make it more configurable, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.