# Why does a reqwest Response hang when switching WiFi networks on macOS / iOS?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I have constructed a proof-of-concept where `tokio::io::copy` will hang forever when switching between Cellular / WiFi / Wired networks if the reader is a `reqwest::async_impl::Response` wrapped in a `tokio_io::AsyncRead` using `FuturesAsyncReadCompatExt`.

This happens on macOS and iOS, which are the platforms I have access to.

- [Full proof-of-concept code (GitHub)](https://github.com/bes/network-switch-hang) (just `cargo run`) (UPDATE: This now contains a fix/workaround as well)
- [ProgressReadAdapter found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621835/how-to-get-callback-update-when-using-tokioiocopy?rq=1), but isn't necessary for the proof-of-concept.
- [Previous attempt at getting help](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/help-tokio-copy-hangs-forever-if-network-is-switched-during-download/90678)
- [Further discussion on GitHub seanmonstar/reqwest](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/discussions/1776)

```rust
#[tokio::main()]
async fn main() {
    let mut target_file = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    target_file.push("bbb.mp4");
    println!("File will be downloaded to {target_file:?}");
    let client = ClientBuilder::default()
        // Doesn't seem to help
        .tcp_keepalive(Some(Duration::from_secs(1)))
        // Doesn't seem to help
        .connect_timeout(Duration::from_secs(1))
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let response = client.get("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_native_60fps_stereo_abl.mp4").send().await.unwrap();
    match response_to_file(response, target_file).await {
        Ok(_) => println!("Everything OK"),
        Err(err) => eprintln!("{err}"),
    }
}

async fn response_to_file(response: Response, path: PathBuf) -> Result<(), ApiError> {
    let download = response.bytes_stream();

    let download = download
        .map_err(|e| futures::io::Error::new(futures::io::ErrorKind::Other, e))
        .into_async_read();

    let download = download.compat();

    // Wrap download to be able to get progress in terminal
    let mut download = ProgressReadAdapter::new(download);

    let temp_file = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(NamedTempFile::new)
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    let mut outfile = tokio::fs::File::create(temp_file.path())
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    // Code hangs here forever after a network switch
    tokio::io::copy(&mut download, &mut outfile)
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    outfile.flush().await.wrap_api_err()?;

    let _persisted_file: File = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || temp_file.persist(path))
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

There are some concepts in the code above, such as `wrap_api_err` that can be found on GitHub, but I don't think they're important for analyzing the problem.

The main question is - How can I make `response_to_file` exit with an `Err` after switching networks?

The second question might be - If there is no easy way to fix this code, how do I make a streaming copy of a network resource to a temp file that actually exits cleanly when there is an error?

Comment: Can you try `tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_secs(1), copy_future).await`? Does that work for you?

Comment: @drewtato Thanks, but that only aborts the download after 1 sec, but it needs much longer to complete. I can't know beforehand how long a user will need to download a given resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to finally reach some conclusions.

[This issue](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/8345) on curl's GitHub page led me to believe that the reason was not `reqwest` but rather the underlying network stack on macOS / iOS.

I asked [this question on seanmonstar/reqwest](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/discussions/1776), which was answered by Sean stating that there was already an issue for a similar idea (low/no-activity timeouts in reqwest).

Basically what I believe is happening is that the network stack has my outstanding response and tries to keep reading more data from the underlying TCP connection even though the original WiFi connection has been "disconnected". As per the curl discussion, this is a thing that just happens and TCP / HTTP isn't at fault so it can't really be detected by client libraries.

What client libraries *can* do is to detect that there is no data coming into the Response (in the case of `reqwest`, at least). Currently, `reqwest` doesn't have this functionality built in, but it can be emulated with a little bit of work.

Using [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621835/how-to-get-callback-update-when-using-tokioiocopy?rq=1) as a starting point I built an `AsyncRead` wrapper that detects a stalled Response and exits cleanly with an error after a given time has elapsed.

The full code can be found on [my GitHub repo bes/network-switch-hang](https://github.com/bes/network-switch-hang), which was originally the repo for the bug proof-of-concept, but is now also an answer.

For completeness, here are the most important parts of the code, at least until `reqwest` grows a native way of detecting stalled Responses.

## main.rs

```rust
#[tokio::main()]
async fn main() {
    let mut target_file = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    target_file.push("bbb.mp4");
    println!("File will be downloaded to {target_file:?}");
    let client = ClientBuilder::default()
        .connect_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5))
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let response = client.get("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_native_60fps_stereo_abl.mp4").send().await.unwrap();
    match response_to_file(response, target_file).await {
        Ok(_) => println!("Everything OK"),
        Err(err) => eprintln!("{err}"),
    }
}

async fn response_to_file(response: Response, path: PathBuf) -> Result<(), ApiError> {
    let download = response.bytes_stream();

    let download = download
        .map_err(|e| futures::io::Error::new(futures::io::ErrorKind::Other, e))
        .into_async_read();

    let download = download.compat();

    // Wrap download to be able to detect stalled downloads
    let mut download = StalledReadMonitor::new(download);

    let temp_file = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(NamedTempFile::new)
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    let mut outfile = tokio::fs::File::create(temp_file.path())
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    // Code used to hang here, but will now exit with an error after being stalled for
    // more than 5 seconds. See StalledReadMonitor for details.
    tokio::io::copy(&mut download, &mut outfile)
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    outfile.flush().await.wrap_api_err()?;

    let _persisted_file: File = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || temp_file.persist(path))
        .await
        .wrap_api_err()?
        .wrap_api_err()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

## stalled_monitor.rs

```rust
/// This monitor can wrap an [AsyncRead] and make sure that it is making progress.
/// If the inner reader isn't making progress, we can stop the download.
/// The monitoring is done by keeping an [Interval] and measuring progress
/// by counting the number of bytes during each interval.
///
/// Please note that this monitor won't stop the download after _exactly_
/// five seconds of inactivity, but rather five seconds after the last interval
/// that had data. So the worst case is 10 seconds, and the averge will be 7.5 seconds.
#[pin_project]
pub struct StalledReadMonitor<R: AsyncRead> {
    #[pin]
    inner: R,
    interval: Interval,
    interval_bytes: usize,
}

impl<R: AsyncRead> StalledReadMonitor<R> {
    pub fn new(inner: R) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner,
            interval: interval_at(
                Instant::now().add(Duration::from_millis(5_000)),
                Duration::from_millis(5_000),
            ),
            interval_bytes: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<R: AsyncRead> AsyncRead for StalledReadMonitor<R> {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
        let this = self.project();

        let before = buf.filled().len();
        let mut result = this.inner.poll_read(cx, buf);
        let after = buf.filled().len();

        *this.interval_bytes += after - before;
        match this.interval.poll_tick(cx) {
            Poll::Pending => {}
            Poll::Ready(_) => {
                if *this.interval_bytes == 0 {
                    println!("Rate is too low, aborting fetch");
                    result = Poll::Ready(Err(std::io::Error::new(
                        ErrorKind::TimedOut,
                        StalledError {},
                    )))
                }
                *this.interval_bytes = 0;
            }
        };
        result
    }
}
```